# android glide into(Target) OOM

Tags: android

I am using Glide frame to load a picture, I want to set the height and the width of it, and I know what is the width I want, but how can I set the height of it.
what I have tried is blow,and I got an error of OOM. waiting for help, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you change `Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL` to some smaller value instead?

Comment: you can use `override` method to resize image while loading image

Comment: Welcome to ST, developer over here will help in better way if you provide more clear description and what all code example you had tried to resolve your issue.

Comment: Don't use screenshot as a question. Use text.

Answer (score 0):

if you want change size

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
    .override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

[Reference](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling)

Answer (score 0):

Using override method of glide you can set the dimension of image in pixels.

```
     Glide 
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .override(50 , 50)
    .into(imageview);
```